# Removing paint from wood: lattice

Tags: paint, removal

I have this gate wood door that was painted. Apparently, they didn't use primer. 
The paint started pealing, so I thought I will strip the paint easily and stain the door (that way I don't need to ever deal with paint again).

So I got this paint scraper[image]
and started going at it. 
but realized quickly, that it is indeed relatively easy and works well for flat, large surface.... but a huge problem when it comes to the lattice area, where there are plenty of corners (where one lattice crosses over the other).

HELP! anyone can recommend a better tool or method? for example, I saw some brushes, are they effective? and if so, which ones (I see 2 different metal color and stiffness).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lattice is really cheap stuff. It's probably easier to just get new lattice and rebuild the gate. Or, for a simple fix, get a wire stripper wheel for a power drill and take at it. Get as much off that comes off easily and then cover it all with quality primer.

FYI, if a lot of the wood has been weathered for a while, it's going to be a chore to get primer to stick to it without a lot of sanding. Again, might be easier to replace the lattice al together. You can also usually find synthetic lattice that doesn't require any painting.

Comment: Agree totally with replace it. Consider composite materials that do not need painting. They come in a variety of colors and are much easier to work with than wood.